# Rejecting some POSTs for some users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This should be a very simple question, yet I keep drawing blanks from DRF documentation.

models.py:

```
class DataPoint(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

serializers.py:

```
class DataPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DataPoint
        fields = ('value', ...)
```

views.py:

```
class DataPointViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DataPoint.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataPointSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    ...
```

I want every logged-in user to be able to GET and POST to this viewset. The only restriction is that non-staff users need to keep value below `100`, something like this:

```
if request.data['value'] > 100 and not request.user.is_staff:
    raise PermissionDeniedValidationErrorWhatareyoudoing("Santaz gonna know")
```

My question boils down to:
**Is this a job for a custom validator or permission?**

Problem with permission is that DRF (specifically `mixins.CreateModelMixin`) will happily save the POSTed data without checking for permissions. Only later are permissions consulted (when `get_object()` is called, AFAICS).

Problem with validators is that they don't have access to `request`, and it seems like an overkill to try to inject the `request` there.

What am I missing?

---

P.S.

Same restriction should be applied to `PUT` and `PATCH` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a job for a custom validator or permission?

This is a validation job.

Validators do have access to the general context through their `set_context` method. See [using set_context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#using-set_context)